# Generically adding set event listener to all ORM columns of custom (TypeDecorator based) datatype

Tags: python, events, sqlalchemy

I have a SQLAlchemy `TypeDecorator` based custom datatype `PathType` which represents a string as `pathlib.Path` object. I'm listening for the `set` event for all columns that use this custom type.

## Current

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
from sqlalchemy.types import TypeDecorator, String
from pathlib import Path
from sqlalchemy import event

class PathType(TypeDecorator):

    impl = String
    cache_ok = True

    def process_bind_param(self, value: Path, dialect):
        if value is not None:
            value = str(value.resolve())

        return value

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if value is not None:
            value = Path(value)

        return value

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class Model(Base):

    __tablename__ = "model"

    path: Mapped[Path] = mapped_column(PathType()) 

def resolve_values_assigned_to_path_type():
    @event.listens_for(Base, 'attribute_instrument')
    def configure_listener(table_cls, attr, col_inst):
        if not hasattr(col_inst.property, 'columns'):
            return
        if isinstance(col_inst.type, PathType):
            # Only decorate PathType columns
            @event.listens_for(col_inst, "set", retval=True)
            def receive_set(target, value: Path, oldvalue, initiator):
                return value.resolve()

model = Model()

resolve_values_assigned_to_path_type()
```

## Desired

However, this doesn't separate the concerns. I don't want to rely on passing a `Base` I want to be able to determine this from the `Column` etc. that `PathType` is attached to.

## Attempted

I have tried listening to the `before_parent_attach` and I can get the correct `Table.Column` but this doesn't seem to have access to the `Base`.

```
@event.listens_for(PathType, "before_parent_attach")
def evt(typ, col):
    @event.listens_for(col, "after_parent_attach")
    def evt2(col, table):
        @event.listens_for(col, "set", retval=True)
        def receive_set(target, value: Path, oldvalue, initiator):
            return value.resolve()
```